# Proving vector norm

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

Quite unsure about this problem.

Prove that for vectors $u, v ∈ R^n$ we have
$$\Vert u + v\Vert^2 +\Vert u − v\Vert^2 = 2 \Vert u\Vert^2 + 2 \Vert v \Vert ^2$$
Can you just expand the left hand part normally, or are there special notations to consider?

Comment: You have to use the fact that $||u||^2=<u,u>$ and the properties of scalar product.

Comment: The parallelogram equation holds iff the norm is derived by an inner product.

Answer (score 1):

$$||u-v||^2=<u-v,u-v>$$
By linearity of the scalar product :
$$||u-v||^2=<u,u>-<u,v>-<v,u>+<v,v>$$
By symetry of the scalar product :
$$||u-v||^2=<u,u>-2<u,v>+<v,v>=||u||^2+||v||^2-2<u,v>$$

Do the same with the other term of the left part of the equality, and you can conclude.